# Can I use Angularjs for my site redesign?

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment

I have a website in which we have used asp.net, c# and SQL database. In this website we are frequently  retrieving/submitting the details from database. Now we are  redesigning this website. How about using Angularjs while redesigning? Will it make the development easier?
Or please let me know if we have better framework for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using basic asp.net, then not really.
You have a page which includes a .cs "code behind" file and a ".aspx" file that are coupled and work together. 
Why would you suddenly need a client side model? This is more relevant for "Asp.net MVC".

Now you could do some work arounds and start working "ajax + json oriented" to insert angularjs, but you will need a lot of changes.

Now, if you are planning on a large redesign, I would try looking at web api(you dont have to change your whole site, but maybe you will prefer to create a service that will work with your database to fetch data and return your angular js client json's that will data-bind with your views).

Now if you didn't understand me, I'd google "Asp.net web api" up and then google some "Asp.net web api and angularjs" up.

Comment: Just wanted to try angularjs as I could hear so much about this framework but i was not sure if this will make my development easier. Looks like using this framework  "ajax + json oriented" may be little difficult for me to implement.

Comment: Maybe you can try it on part of your site(if there's a module that works "directly" with your DB, I'd create a web api controller for fetching the data and bind that data using angular).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AngularJS can be used to simplify the front-end side of your website development.

Their developer overview provides a great brief on how to do data binding: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding